# MAPE or sMAPE or wMAPE in regression problem

Tags: regression, metrics

I am currentely working on a regression problem and I want to use a normalized version of the RMSE as an evaluation metric of my models that computes a percentage of the error regarding the actual value. My dependant variable Y is positive strictly (Y>0). So I have done my research on these metrics and i found out that there are a lot of metrics that are like RMSE but are normalized (MAPE for example it divides by the actual value) but i am afraid that it is used only for forecasting (time series) and not regression problems. Moreover, these metrics are assymetric (it is strongly biased when forecast is less than the actual; in this case it reports lower errors than than the case when the forecast is more than the actual). So what i want to know is there a symetric metric to use on my regression problem that would compute a percentage error taking on consideration the size of the actual values?

I tried RMSE but i find that it is not best suitable for my problem.